Advice on using vias to connect two sides of a PCB together to maintain a circuit through a copper plate
I am currently designing a circuit for an intelligent reflective surface system where varactors are used to control the resonance of a unit cell through the capacitance they produce which will control the phase of the reflected waves (around 2-5 GHz). The design will have 10 unit cells connected in parallel. Due to the requirements of the top PCB, only varactors can be placed on the surface everything else has to be placed on the other side of the copper plate. The components for this system are distributed across two PCBs:
PCB 1 houses varactor diodes.
PCB 2 houses the biasing resistors.
Control PCB houses the DAC which is connected to our FPGA controller which outputs desired bias voltages (between 0.5-4 V) for the varactors:

Between these two PCBs, I have a large copper plate that is integral to the circuit. The copper plate is required as it reflects electromagnetic waves, ensuring that the incident signals interact efficiently with the metasurface (PCB 1).
The Circuit Overview:
The varactor diodes are in parallel, each with a biasing resistor in series. These are connected to the DAC output and ground. I've attached a schematic to provide a clear picture of the circuit, if there are any glaring errors in the circuit please let me know what.

Is there a 'best' way to design the vias to ensure reliable connections? Are there any rules of thumb for size, placement, or the number of vias? I was also hoping for advice on how I should route the traces to minimise signal loss or noise issues, especially since the copper plate might complicate things. I am trying to design this in KiCAD so any specific advice for KiCAD would be appreciated
As I am new to PCB design, I really appreciate any advice or links to resources that can help me with this.

Your schematic is wrong.

What speeds are involved?  If it's not too great (say, less than 20 MHz), you could just use press in pins, soldered if need be, to connect between the two boards.  We did things like this 40 years ago.

And, do you really need the solid copper plate?  There are other ways to achieve structural rigidity and thermal conductance.

The copper plate is necessary as the top pcb is being used as a metasurface that will be used to beamform signals through reflection. This is all part of an IRS system

What wavelength are the varactors being used at? Are you familiar with the concept of a "bias tee"?

The logic diagram is missing a description of your intentions, specs and expectations.  None of these are obvious which makes your question less relevant.  Many small varactor diodes can be replace with one large diode but even so, makes no sense as a filter.

I have tried to improve the question above to more clearly explain the intention of the circuit, but if anyone still has questions for clarification let me know. In terms of the bias tee it may be worth considering i shall look into it as i am not super familiar but i expect i would still have the issues of components being on opposite sides of a copper plate, but would that be a better way to ensure expected circuit performance?

@Andyaka I have tried to fix my schematic based on similar examples i found online using LEDs, but i was hoping you could let me know what the specific issue you have seen in my schematic is if you wouldn't mind
